# How in tailwindcss to make footer with 2 buttons Cancel and Save right aligned

Tags: tailwind-css

With tailwindcss I make footer with 2 buttons Cancel and Save right aligned:

```
<div class="p-2 flex">
    <div class="w-1/2">Empty Space</div>
    <div class="w-1/2">
        <button type="submit" class="bg-gray-500 text-white p-2 rounded text-sm w-auto float-right">
            Cancel
        </button>
        <button type="submit" class="bg-yellow-500 text-white p-2 ml-6 rounded text-lg w-auto float-right ">
            Save
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

It works, but different I need : Cancel aligned right after save, not beofre as I need.

Which way is correct ?

Thanks!

Comment: `I need : Cancel aligned right after save, not beofre as I need` can you please explain?

Comment: If you add a quick drawing explaining what you want it would be helpful

Comment: I need like that : https://prnt.sc/yuq18z

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`float-right` will place elements from right to left, so you just need to switch the order of the Cancel and Save buttons:

```
<div class="p-2 flex">
    <div class="w-1/2">Empty Space</div>
    <div class="w-1/2">
        <button type="submit" class="bg-yellow-500 text-white p-2 ml-6 rounded text-lg w-auto float-right ">
            Save
        </button>
        <button type="submit" class="bg-gray-500 text-white p-2 rounded text-sm w-auto float-right">
            Cancel
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

I prefer using `flex justify-end` in the parent element instead of using `float-right`

```html
<div class="p-2 flex">
    <div class="w-1/2">Empty Space</div>
    <div class="w-1/2 flex justify-end">
        <button type="submit" class="bg-gray-500 text-white p-2 rounded text-sm w-auto">
            Cancel
        </button>
        <button type="submit" class="bg-yellow-500 text-white p-2 ml-6 rounded text-lg w-auto">
            Save
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's an example using Tailwind Play

https://play.tailwindcss.com/CY54ArgXe4